# Trying to split javascript string, says undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can you please look at this function and tell me where the error is? Firebug says that "string is undefined" ... Any help is appreciated. 
(links is declared above, console.debug(string) shows a comma delimited string)

```
function adRotate() {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length);
    var string = links[id];
    var item = string.split(',');
    console.debug(item);
}
```

Comment: Add a `console.log(links)` as the first line of your function, I suspect that it'll return `undefined`.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't really be using `string` as a variable name.

Comment: @DavidThomas. No it won't, it can't be. he would have got a `ReferenceError` in that case.

Comment: Naming a variable "string" is not really a good idea.  Could cause confusion - like thinking the error message is talking about your  "string" variable when its actually talking about another variable of type string.

Comment: If "links" contains just a single string, your code isn't going to work anyway. When you index into a string with a numeric property name like that, you get back the single character at that position in the string.

Comment: Also if "links" is an empty string then "id" will always be zero and "string" will be `undefined`.

Comment: @gdoron links is declared outside of the function, and when console.debug(links) is called  it outputs the value of the array [Object { id="2", banner="main_ad.jpg"}, Object { id="1", banner="Colorado_banner.jpg"}] (also it is defined as array so if it only has one string it shoudl be array element 0)

Comment: @Chad. Please post a demo in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Is links a true string or the array of objects it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work. If the console "*shows a comma delimited string*", this should either be a string or an Array.

In case `adRotate(["one,link", "second,link,"])` - links is an `Array` - you'd get:

```
function adRotate(links) {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length); // valid index in links
    var str = links[id]; // selects one of the links: str is a String
    var item = str.split(','); // splits the string to an Array
    console.debug(item); // logs the array
}
```

possible results: `["one","link"]` or `["second","link"]`

In case `adRotate("one link, and second")` - links is a `String` - you'd get:

```
function adRotate(links) {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length); // valid index in links
    var str = links[id]; // selects one of the chars in the string: str is a String of length 1
    var item = str.split(','); // splits the one-char-string to an Array
    console.debug(item); // logs the array
}
```

possible results: `["o"]`, `["n"]`,  `["e"]`,  `[" "]`, ..., `["k"]`, `["",""]` (for the comma char),  `["i"]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this got me on the right path (that is being that this function *should* work).... turned out that I shoudl call adRotate() from the success callback of my jquery getJSON b/c on window load the variable was in fact not defined... thanks for all the help !